# How to secure your php apis

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, postman

I am writing an api in php with post method.
But what if somebody changes the request body in postman and send some data which does not belongs to the current logged in user.
for-example:

If my api receives a book_id to delete it. And what if the client sends a book_id which does not belongs to this client?

Comment: Read https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization.

Comment: You add a check to the API that prevents users from deleting data that doesn't belong to them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport) or [JWT](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) for API authentication in Laravel

Or add an `api_token` column to **Users**  table, User should send his unique **api_token** for each request , You authorize users based on it

Answer (score 0):

One way to protect against this is by creating a middleware that checks if the user_id is the same that the user authenticated. The `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware would be a good place to get an understanding how to do this. You'd need something along the lines of:

```
if (auth()->user()->id === request()->input('user_id')) {
    // it's a good request

    return $request($next);
}

abort(403, "Unauthorized");
```